# AutoHotkey script is disabling numpad 0 key?

Tags: autohotkey

I am currently trying to write a script for ahk, I thought I finally got it working but it seems now my numpad 0 is disabled. Here is the script I am using:

```
Numpad0 & Left::Run C:\Program Files\Virtual Audio Cable\VAC bat\Line 1 to Hdpn.bat

Numpad0 & Right::Run C:\Program Files\Virtual Audio Cable\VAC bat\Line 1 to Multi.bat

Numpad0 & Up::Run C:\Program Files\Virtual Audio Cable\VAC bat\Stop Repeaters.bat

Numpad0 & Down::Run C:\Program Files\Virtual Audio Cable\VAC bat\Line 1 to Spkr.bat
```

I'm just trying to run some .bat files corresponding to an arrow key and 0 on the numpad being pressed simltaneously. However, though these commands execute my desired functions, they disable actually typing zeros from the numpad! How can I fix this in my script? thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question "why", though the first key is disabled  in a combination like that in AutoHotKey_L, but why not use the `R Ctrl` instead of `0`/`Ins`. Both keys are close to the arrows and `Ctrl` works without any problems.

Comment: It is more comfortable on my right hand, not to mention I like keeping my right ctrl reserved for my VMachine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```
~Numpad0::return
```

To you code.

Comment: I added the suggested code underneath my code I was trying to run and it worked perfect. Thanks so much!